# Factorial Code issue

Tags: c, math

Here is my code to find a factorial. The first code is giving error in the output when I am trying to find the factorial of numbers more than 50.

```
#include<stdio.h>
short int t,i;
int count=0;
int num[100];
long long int fac = 1;
main()
{
scanf("%d",&t);
for(count=0;count<t;count++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&num[count]);
    }
for(count=0;count<t;count++)    
{
    int k= num[count];
    fac =1;
    for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
    {
        fac *= i;
    }    
    printf("%lld\n",fac);
}    
}
```

But the code below is working fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    long T,N,i,j,digits,rem,x,a[200];
    scanf("%ld",&T);
    while(T--){
        scanf("%ld",&N);
        a[0]=1;
        digits=1;
        rem=0;
        for(i=1;i<=N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<digits;j++){
            x=a[j]*i+rem;
            a[j]=x%10;
            rem=x/10;
        }

        while(rem){
            a[digits]=rem%10;
            rem/=10;
            digits++;
        }
        }
        for(i=digits-1;i>=0;i--)
        printf("%ld",a[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

why is this happening to the first code irrespective of using long long int and in the second it is just long but it is still working!! Can someone explain?

Comment: 50! is a very big number. Does that number fit into a `long long`?

Comment: Does the word "digits" ring some kind of bell?

Comment: 50! is about 3*10^64, or 2^214. Poor `long long int` has only 64 bits...

Comment: what can be done for this?

Comment: @AlexP: "has only 64 bits" -> "has only at least 64 bits".

Comment: *what can be done for this?*  That question is answered by the second code snippet you show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clever authors of the second snippet are rolling their own method of dealing with a very large number such as `50!`. Is rather like a multiprecision library and factorial algorithm rolled into one.

The first snippet has no such consideration. Even `21!` will overflow a signed 64 bit integral type, with undefined results.